# Teams Toolkit keeps wanting to use expired certificate

Tags: teams-toolkit

The following are the errors I receive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDG10.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJpMz.png)

I have tried everything in the following documentation.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/%7BDebug%7D-Teams-Toolkit-VS-Code-Tasks#start-local-tunnel

And I've tried every variation of deleting and recreating certifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to initiate the dev tunnel CLI? Did this issue occur when you used the dev tunnel CLI directly?

Detail Steps:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/8970#issuecomment-1752462443